# Get the value of dynamic check boxes in angular js when submitting the form

Tags: angularjs, forms, checkbox

In my HTML form there are 5 check boxes. How can I check which check boxes are checked or not at the time of the form submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Checklist-model](https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/) of Angular.js. It is very useful:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["checklist-model"]);
app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope) {
  $scope.roles = [
    'guest', 
    'user', 
    'customer', 
    'admin'
  ];
  $scope.user = {
    roles: ['user']
  };
  $scope.checkAll = function() {
    $scope.user.roles = angular.copy($scope.roles);
  };
  $scope.uncheckAll = function() {
    $scope.user.roles = [];
  };
  $scope.checkFirst = function() {
    $scope.user.roles.splice(0, $scope.user.roles.length); 
    $scope.user.roles.push('guest');
  };
  $scope.showCheckedOnes = function() {
    var checkedBoxes = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.user.roles.length; i++) {
      checkedBoxes += $scope.user.roles[i] + " ";
    }
    alert(checkedBoxes);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/checklist-model.js"></script>

  <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">

      <label ng-repeat="role in roles">
        <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.roles" checklist-value="role"> {{role}}
      </label>

    <div>
  <div>
  <button ng-click="checkAll()" style="margin-right: 10px">Check all</button>
  <button ng-click="uncheckAll()" style="margin-right: 10px">Uncheck all</button>
  <button ng-click="checkFirst()" style="margin-right: 10px">Check first</button>
  <button ng-click="showCheckedOnes()" style="margin-right: 10px">Show checked ones</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for spending your valuable time for my question.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this little piece of code. Feel free to take it.

In your controller:

```
$scope.sentinel = [];

$scope.toggleSelection = function(value) {              
            // Bit trick, equivalent to "contains"
            if (~$scope.sentinel.indexOf(value)) {
                var idx = $scope.sentinel.indexOf(value);
                $scope.sentinel.splice(idx, 1);
                return;
            }

            $scope.sentinel.push(value);
        };
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<span ng-repeat="key in $scope.yourarray">
    <md-checkbox style="margin-left:30px;" aria-label="Select item"
    ng-click="toggleSelection(key)"><span>{{ key }}</span></md-checkbox>
    <br/>
</span>
```

This allows you to have an array of any size and using the `sentinel` array to register already checked values. If you check again a box, the `toogleSelection` will prevent you from adding again a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the array value and map to html.

```
$scope.checkbox = [];
```

HTML

```
<input ng-model="checkbox[0] type="checkbox" />
<input ng-model="checkbox[1] type="checkbox" />
<input ng-model="checkbox[2] type="checkbox" />
<input ng-model="checkbox[4] type="checkbox" />
```

Or you can define checkbox as object and change checkbox[index] to checkbox[name].